# positioning UIBarButtonItem vertically (for iPhone X)

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, iphone-x

I'm trying to compile my app to work correctly with the iPhone X, using all the available screen space and accommodating the new home indicator at the bottom of the screen. My app has a bottom toolbar, and I notice that Apple's apps extend the height of the bottom toolbar to give extra room for the home indicator. I give my toolbar extra height, but the buttons themselves want to position toward the bottom instead of the top. Is it possible to force them to align toward the top of the toolbar instead of toward the bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: I've had the same issue, only when the view is displayed in an indirect way (after transitioning from the View Controller's default view to a second view using animated transition). I think the clue is in there somewhere, and I couldn't find a way to directly control the alignment in the toolbar unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app for which I asked the question, I am positioning views on the screen using coordinates. (In a constraint based app, one would need to pin the bottom constraint of a bottom toolbar to the safe area rather than the superview; if you are using the built-in bottom toolbar belonging to the navigation controller, the position of the toolbar and its content will take care of itself). Surprisingly, the solution turned out to be simply lifting the bottom toolbar up using its y coordinate, no more than 34 pts, and the area below the toolbar and near the home indicator will simply assume the color of the bottom toolbar, making it appear as though that area is part of a taller-than-normal bottom toolbar. The buttons on the toolbar will no longer appear squished.

Comment: can you please elaborate more, how you fix this part ? I am facing the sam issue. May be some code ?

Comment: I don't have the code available to me where I am now. But all I did was move the toolbar up a bit; I did not have to increase the height of the toolbar or do anything special regarding the alignment of the buttons.